# how can i change status bar color(primary dark and primary) in android and ios in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am changing the status bar color by changing the color in styles in xamarin forms

```
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#fc3884</item>//android
   UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(232, 62,140);//ios
        UITabBar.Appearance.BarTintColor=UIColor.FromRGB(232, 62, 140);
```

but in my project, I am using 3rd party API,I have to change statusbar color while I am navigating to a new page(3rd party)also.how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android, you can change the status bar color using dependency service. You can set the following function in your android project and call it from the .net standard project.

```
public bool ChangeStatusbarColor(Color color)
{
     bool colorChanged = false;
     try
     {
 #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        var context = Forms.Context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
        context.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToAndroid());
 #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            colorChanged = true;
     }
     catch { }
        return colorChanged;
}
```

For IOS, you can do something similar with the following function:

```
UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
{
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = color.ToUIColor();
}
```